# How to make dynamic Jquery ul Append?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make dynamic ul append to create receivers and senders messages.

Check my html and css code:

```
<ul>
              <li class="sent">
                <img src="http://emilcarlsson.se/assets/mikeross.png" alt="" />
                <p>How the hell am I supposed to get a jury to believe you when I am not even sure that I do?!</p>
              </li>
              <li class="replies">
                <img src="http://emilcarlsson.se/assets/harveyspecter.png" alt="" />
                <p>When you're backed against the wall, break the god damn thing down.</p>
              </li>
            </ul>
```

I got json from replies and senders.
Need to make this logic :

```
 if(data.socketmessage.senderID === nickname.val()){
                    append to sender
                } else{
                    append to receiver
                }
```

Comment: You're asking how to append HTML to what? The content of `li.sent` and `li.replies`, or...?

Comment: Yes i need to make dynamic li.sent and li.replies @DaveNewton

Comment: What's dynamic? The content of the list item, or the list? Right now you have a single list. Perhaps an example of the expected resulting HTML would help clarify things. In any case, there are countless examples/tutorials that describe how to create HTML through jQuery.

Comment: I have done this but not showing the results from json

Comment: $chat.append('<li class="' + data.colorClass + '"><b>' + data.socketmessage.date + ': </b>' + data.socketmessage.text + "<br/></li>");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [html template tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_template.asp) and a javascript function to [add the class](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_add_class.asp) you want.

```js
function addChat(className, imgSource, chatText) {
  var temp = document.getElementsByTagName("template")[0];
  var clon = temp.content.cloneNode(true);

  var list = document.getElementById("chatList");
  list.appendChild(clon);

  var newLine = list.lastElementChild;

  newLine.classList.add(className);

  newLine.firstElementChild.src = imgSource;
  newLine.lastElementChild.innerHTML = chatText;

  return newLine;
}

function addTestChat() {
  console.log(addChat("sent", "http://via.placeholder.com/100x100", "Sending a test..."));
}
```

```html
<ul id="chatList">
  <li class="sent">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="" />
    <p>How the hell am I supposed to get a jury to believe you when I am not even sure that I do?!</p>
  </li>
  <li class="replies">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="" />
    <p>When you're backed against the wall, break the god damn thing down.</p>
  </li>
</ul>

<button onclick="addTestChat()">
Test
</button>

<template>
  <li >
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="" />
    <p>When you're backed against the wall, break the god damn thing down.</p>
  </li>
</template>
```

**See [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vxubhc8o/19/)**